# Empty sum() on condition

Tags: sql-server, aggregate-functions

```
SELECT    Column_A, SUM(CASE WHEN COLUMN_B = 'x' THEN 1 ELSE 'SET SUM TO 0' END) as total
FROM      table 
GROUP BY  Column_A
ORDER BY  Month
```

Is there a way to set the value of sum to 0 , I am trying to find the sum of last consecutive x value for cloumn_B if the consecution breaks I need to set the sum to 0

```
Table
ColumnA Column B Month
A        x        1
A        x        2
A        x        3
A        y        4

B        x        1
B        y        2
B        x        3
B        x        4

C        x        1
C        x        2
C        y        3
C        x        4

The expected result is:
A    0
B    2
C    1
```

Answer (score 1):

EDIT:

```
DECLARE @TEMP TABLE (columnA varchar(50), maxMonth int )

INSERT INTO @TEMP (columnA, maxMonth)
SELECT columnA, MAX([Month]) FROM [table]
WHERE columnB != 'x'
GROUP BY columnA

SELECT original.columnA, SUM(CASE when original.[Month] > withMax.maxMonth THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS TOTAL 
FROM @TEMP withMax JOIN [table] original ON withMax.columnA = original.columnA
WHERE original.columnB = 'x'
GROUP BY original.columnA
```

This query should work for you.

Comment: This gives the total count where column_B = 'x'

Comment: Yep, you were summing "1" where column_B = 'x'. That is the same. You can give an example of your data and what you expect to return if we understood you incorrectly.

Comment: Edited for data and expected results

Answer (score 0):

Just try this

```
SELECT    Column_A, SUM(CASE WHEN COLUMN_B = 'x' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as total
FROM      table 
GROUP BY  Column_A
ORDER BY  some_date
```

`SUM` cannot be used for *non-numeric data types*

If you use, you will get error

> Operand data type char is invalid for sum operator.

```
SELECT    Column_A, ISNULL(CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN COLUMN_B = 'x' THEN 1 END) AS VARCHAR),'SET SUM TO 0') AS total
FROM      table 
GROUP BY  Column_A
ORDER BY  some_date
```

Comment: I dont intend to add non-numeric data but set the sum to 0 on else condition i.e when column_B is not 'x'

Comment: What is your expected output? SUM() OR 'SET SUM TO 0' right?